# Problems with recognizing Ubuntu after Windows 10 Dual-Boot Installation

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I have a Dell Inspiron 17-5767 Laptop with Windows 10 home edition. I am trying to make it a Dual-Boot with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Desktop. I installed Ubuntu using Rufus on a 32 GB USB.

When I plug in the USB and start with F12 option, it works fine and recognizes and runs Ubuntu from the USB drive. Then I installed Ubuntu on the hard disk letting Ubuntu split the hard disk and install alongside Windows 10.

Installation shows as successful, and hard disk space is broken up almost equally between two OS's.  When I reboot after installing by hitting power button, a screen pops up (Magenta colored offering Ubuntu, advanced Ubuntu and Windows Server as options).  Select Ubuntu, it starts up.  Shut down, then restart with power, and the Magenta screen comes up again.  Shutdown, select Windows, and Windows 10 pops up.  Shutdown, Startup again, and this time you get no magenta screen offering options, only Windows 10 startup.  If you restart using F12 repeatedly to activate BIOS settings, etc., only Windows 10 shows up as Boot system option.  Run with Ubuntu USB drive in, and rerun F12 option, and it will recognize both Ubuntu and Windows.

If I use Disk Manager to review partitioning, it shows 16 GB  swap and 868 GB other as main region for files under Ubuntu. If you reinstall Ubuntu, it seems to recognizes these partitions as previous Ubuntu installation, and will remove and reinstall at these locations successfully.  So, problem seems to be after installation and startup with Windows, it no longer recognizes Ubuntu installation.  This is with UEFI and Secure Boot disabled, including throughout installation.

What else can I do or what might be the problem?

Comment: An Windows update might have moved the Windows bootloader to the first boot entry at UEFI boot settings but if that was the case, simply selecting Ubuntu again would boot Grub again.

Comment: @windows sets itself as first in the boot order.

Comment: I have an almost identical problem. When I installed Ubuntu 16.04.03 for the first time, everything worked. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, using the "Erase" option.  At the end it produced a fault message and got stuck. When I try to boot, it shows on the display "grub>" but doesn't do anything. I can boot both Windows and Ubuntu if I hit F12 during the boot and choose the right option under "Legacy boot" which is bothersome. Tried to use "repair-boot" which seems simple, but it tells me to turn UEFI on; if I do it, it tells me to turn secure boot off. Those two options are connected! Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try running **boot-repair** when you succeed booting Ubuntu either from your HDD or from a live USB. A tutorial can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/). It worked for me in getting back the GRUB menu on every boot.